# Stop a formula when another is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, cell-format

In column A I have employees put a date in and I have formatted as date. In column H I want it to auto calculate 2 yr anniversary of the date they put into Column A which I have done using the cell +730.

I then have that highlight red when it’s past today’s date using conditional formatting. But it keeps putting all of the columns H red with the date +730 from Jan 1  when there’s no data in a cell in column A.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1744967/edit) your question and add the formula.

Comment: Ok think I’ve updated it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please set the essential and correct tags. Do you want your question answered for Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Yes excel.. my apologies… I will read through and update tonight.

Comment: How does it look now?

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information beforehand.

For Excel, the calculation of time begins with the number 0, which means the unreal date `0.0.1900` for Excel. Counting starts from there.
A cell formatted as a date therefore displays a "converted" number, only formatted as a date taking into account the local settings. Provided it meets the Excel date criteria, namely that it is >= 0 and <= than 2958465 (9999-12-31). Excel can process data in this range. This means nothing other than that you cannot enter/edit/calculate dates before 1900-01-01 and after 9999-12-31 as dates.

---

I assume you have a formula such as `=IF(A2<>"", A2+730,"")` to avoid the e.g. 1901-12-30 or 12/30/1901 and a first conditional formatting rule like shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

- Open the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager dialog box by clicking **Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules** under Home tab as shown in the screenshot above.
- Click the `New Rule` button.
- Then it gets into the **New Formatting Rule** dialog box.

[image]

- Select `Format only cells that contain` in the *Select a Rule Type* box.
- Select `Blanks` in the *Format only cells with* drop-down list.
- Don't select any format and click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

It returns to the **Conditional Formatting Rules Manager** dialog. Check the *Stop If True* box, and then click the <kbd>Apply</kbd>or <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

[image]

You still have to adapt this for your requirements. For test case you may want to use `Clear Rules` for old formatting rules.

Comment: Thank you!   I am actually trying to avoid the 12/30/1901 from showing up when there’s no data in column A but go red when it’s past today. The formula doesn’t seem to do that?

Comment: @Orrlakegrl - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Column H and go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...**- **Use a formula to determine with cells to format** and create 2 rules for column H:

```
=&H1=730
=TODAY()<$A1+730
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I’m actually trying to avoid 12/30/1901 from showing and just want it blank when there’s nothing in column A and only when my staff put a date in column A I want it to highlight it when it’s greater than today in red. Doesn’t seem to work