# Conditional formatting when date complete is later than due date in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm putting together a new spreadsheet for my team where I'm tracking "batches" and their approval through the system. The spreadsheet will list 200+ batches per month and each batch has a different due date. I would like to apply conditional formatting where when I populate the date completed, it will highlight it in green if its earlier or equal to the due date, and in red if its later than the due date. I've tried everything I can think of and can only get it to work on one row. When I try to copy it down it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: are you using a formula in the conditional formatting? Check to make sure that formula is using relative cell reference

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for a sample of the formula you are using that does not work?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://superuser.com/a/1744985/214658 and other answers. Improve your question later.

Comment: I can display the requirements fine after testing with excel. Did you choose to keep the format when pasting?